# Java loop to ask 10 maths questions

Tags: java

Im currently trying to create a program thats asks the user to answer 10 multiplication questions and then output if the answer is correct or incorrect and then keep score of how many answers the user has got correct. My current code is shown below but I'm having trouble getting the score to increase as whenever I run it the score always stays at 1. I was wondering if anyone could help me with a solution to this

```
package Assignment1;
import java.util.Scanner;
import static java.lang.System.in;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        for (int i = 0; i < 11; i++) {
            int number1 = (int) (Math.random() * 10) + 10;
            int number2 = (int) (Math.random() * 10) + 10;
            Scanner input = new Scanner(in);
            System.out.print("What is " + number1 + " * " + number2 + " ?");
            int answer = input.nextInt();

            while ((number1 * number2) != answer) {
                System.out.print("Incorrect");
                answer = input.nextInt();
            }

            if ((number1 * number2) == answer) {
                System.out.println("Correct");
                int score = 0;
                score = score + 1;
                System.out.println("Score is currently: " + score);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Your variables are incorrectly scoped. I will not mention some optimizations that you can do, but your `score` variable should be outside the top for loop.

Comment: your outer most for loop will loop a total of 11 times, also, since your while loop continues until you answer the question correctly, your score (once placed outside your outer most for loop) will always be equal to the total number of times you ask the question. remove the while loop

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order to solve your problem, you need to understand the variable `scope`. The `scope` of a variable is in plain simple english: its lifecycle. And its lifecycle is defined between curly brackets, and by that I mean if the variable is created after "`{`", it only lives until "`}`". There are other cases, but don't mind them for now.

With this in mind, let's analyse what's the problem here. In your program you want the 'score' variable to live under all calculations and keep changing by adding the previous score to the new result, therefore producing a new score on every iteration. **NOT to create a 'score' on every iteration.**

Notice that you are creating the variable 'score' on every loop - resulting on its value being erased from memory (actually, its reference is what's being erased making its value lost in memory) at the end of every loop (when it dies) and a new 'score' variable is created over the next iteration.

So, I guess you'd know how to change your code now. You just change the creation of the variable 'score' to before the loop - so it's created before the "`{`" from the `for` loop instead of being erased and created on every iteration.

```
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int score = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < 11; i++) {
            int number1 = (int) (Math.random() * 10) + 10;
            int number2 = (int) (Math.random() * 10) + 10;
            Scanner input = new Scanner(in);
            System.out.print("What is " + number1 + " * " + number2 + " ?");
            int answer = input.nextInt();

            while ((number1 * number2) != answer) {
                System.out.print("Incorrect");
                answer = input.nextInt();
            }

            if ((number1 * number2) == answer) {
                System.out.println("Correct");
                score = score + 1;
                System.out.println("Score is currently: " + score);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thankyou for your response this was very helpful however I'm having another issue in that I want the score to stay the same when I answer the questions incorrectly however I'm discovering whenever I answer a question incorrectly the score still goes up.

Comment: @Nick That happens because when you answer wrong, you keep inside the while loop. Assume that the second time the answer is right, it exits the while loop and encounters the 'if' statement, which is true because now he answered correctly. To the 'if' statement it doesn't matter how many times the user failed, it only matters that the answer is right when it gets there - because at that point the expression is correct.

Comment: Try to solve it by yourself first, but my move would be to put the if statement first, and then put the while loop inside an 'else' statement. Reason: if the answer is right, it enters the 'if's body, incrementing the score, and never gets to the while loop. If the answer is incorrect, it goes to the while loop and at that point never more has the chance of incrementing the score. Besides that, it only computes the while when really needed - improving computation performance.

Comment: @nick if that solved your problem, please consider upvoting my answer or making it the answer to the question. Have a good coding!

Comment: Okay I have added an if/else statement however I would like the score to show up and then generate a new question whenever the user answers a question incorrectly e.g. "What is 19 * 10" then the user answers incorrectly e.g. '21' and the output to be "Incorrect score is currently 4/10" then ask another question. Apologies if my earlier comment was confusing.

Comment: This is my updated code: if ((number1 * number2) == answer) {
                System.out.println("Correct");
                score++;
                System.out.println("Score is currently: " + score + "/10");
            } else {
                while ((number1 * number2) != answer) {
                    System.out.print("Incorrect");
                    answer = input.nextInt();
                }

Comment: @Nick if you dont want to repeat the question (and move to another one instead of insisting on the same question) don't use the while loop, since it's what is making you loop. Inside the 'else' statement eliminate the 'while' loop and just print that to the screen. The while is what's keeping questioning the user everytime the answer is wrong

Answer (score 1):

You have declared `score` variable in the if block. So everytime there is a correct answer, the `score` is initialized with 0, then set to 1. Declare the score as an instance variable, or a local variable in main method (before the for loop)

Answer (score 0):

If you want only 10 questions, the for loop should go from `i = 1` to `i < 11`, not from `i = 0`. Also, you need to move the score outside the for loop, otherwise it will be declared as 0 every time the loop starts again. As Telmo Vaz correctly said, this is due to the scope of the variable. One other thing I noticed is that you can just use `score++` to add 1 to score, instead of `score = score + 1`. I'll leave you to optimise your further.

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import static java.lang.System.in;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int score = 0;
        for (int i = 1; i < 11; i++) {       // 1 -> 10
            int number1 = (int) (Math.random() * 10) + 10;
            int number2 = (int) (Math.random() * 10) + 10;
            Scanner input = new Scanner(in);
            System.out.print("What is " + number1 + " * " + number2 + " ?");
            int answer = input.nextInt();

            while ((number1 * number2) != answer) {
                System.out.print("Incorrect");
                answer = input.nextInt();
            }

            if ((number1 * number2) == answer) {
                System.out.println("Correct");
                score++;         // == (score = score + 1)
                System.out.println("Score is currently: " + score);
            }
        }
    }
}
```